# Can not get jQuery & Javascript If statement to unselect / select class based on object click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get on click function to close an accordion item and remove classes from all other elements except the one I am interacting with

I have tried various if statements with different parameters.

```
// Container For Each Accordion Item
var $expandeditemcontainer = $('.expand-wrapper');

// Accordion/Card Head - Summary Box - Once Clicked Expands .expanded-box
var $expandingsummarybox = $('.expander');

// Accordion/Card Body - Expanded Box That Appears Underneath - Absolutely Positioned - Out Of Document Flow
var $expandedbox = $('.expanded-box');

// Ghost Div replicating Accordion/Card Body's Height - Relatively Positioned - In Document Flow
var $expandedboxspacer = $('.expand-box-height-clearance');

// When $expandingsummarybox is clicked
$($expandingsummarybox).click(function() {

  /** .expand-focus creates outline on $expandingsummarybox once accordion is opened **/

  // If any $expandingsummarybox has a class .expander-focus applied
  if ($($expandingsummarybox).hasClass('expander-focus')) {
    // Remove .expander-focus from all $expandingsummarybox's
    $($expandingsummarybox).removeClass('expander-focus');
    // Close all Accordion Item's
    $($expandingsummarybox).closest($expandeditemcontainer).find($expandedboxspacer).slideUp(200, 'swing');

    // If any $expandingsummarybox does NOT have .expander-focus applied
  } else if (!$($expandingsummarybox).hasClass('expander-focus')) {
    // Add .expander-focus to this specific  $expandingsummarybox
    $(this).addClass('expander-focus');
    // Open this specific Accordion Item 
    $(this).closest($expandeditemcontainer).find($expandedboxspacer).slideDown(200, 'swing');

  } else {
    // These were the parameters I was originally using affecting that specific item
    $(this).toggleClass('expander-focus');
    $(this).closest($expandeditemcontainer).find($expandedboxspacer).slideToggle(200, 'swing');
  }
});
```

Works when interacting with the initial clicked item but when trying to close via a different method or clicking on another accordion item it breaks.

Comment: `$expandingsummarybox` is already a jquery object, no reason to wrap it in the jquery function.

Comment: it would really help if you included the relevant markup and styling.

Comment: make a codepen or something with your html so we can help. Need a visiual of that animation.

Comment: Like @Iwrestledabearonce. said you don't need to wrap `$expandingssummarybox` in a jQuery function. What might be breaking is that when the you click on another `.expander` it's hitting that first if statement and closing all of the accordions but if you look at the control flow it never hits the code to open the `.expander` that was clicked (if it actually needs to be opened). You'd need to re-order some of the logic and control flow but I think that's might be your issue

Comment: To continue a bit on my last comment, at the top of the event handler determine if the current `.expander` being clicked is open or closed at the moment. Then close all `.expander` accordions. Finally if the current handler was closed at the beginning open it, otherwise it was open and closing all `.expander`'s closed it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see some logic errors in your click handler but without some more detail on what/how it is breaking this might not be a complete solution.

Your problem is the control flow in if/else-if block. The first time an `.expander` is clicked it will open properly. However, if you click a different `.expander` it will hit the if statement block and close all `.expander-box` but never actually opens the `.expander` that was clicked.

To solve this you should first determine if the `.expander` that was clicked is open or closed. Then you can close all the `.expander` boxes. Finally if the `.expander` that was clicked was originally closed you can open it. Otherwise if the expander was opened then closing all of the `.expander` boxes closed it for you.

```
const $expandeditemcontainer = $('.expand-wrapper');
const $expandingsummarybox = $('.expander');
const $expandedbox = $('.expanded-box');
const $expandedboxspacer = $('.expand-box-height-clearance');

$expandingsummarybox.click(function() {

    const isCurrentExpanded = $(this).hasClass("expander-focus");

    // Remove .expander-focus from all $expandingsummarybox's
    $expandingsummarybox.removeClass('expander-focus');

    // Close all Accordion Item's
    $expandingsummarybox.closest($expandeditemcontainer).find($expandedboxspacer).slideUp(200, 'swing');

    if (!isCurrentExpanded) {
        // The clicked expander was closed originally lets open it
        $(this).addClass('expander-focus');
        $(this).closest($expandeditemcontainer).find($expandedboxspacer).slideDown(200, 'swing');
    }

});
```

Comment: Hi Shreddish, Thank you very much for your help!. Sorry I have not given further assets on what it involves it is due to privacy matters, but that has fixed it. I just need to now allow an icon I have inside the expanded box to close the particular box in question.